# web interface port for oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, linux

I am running a fresh Oracle 11g installation created on lunix redhat 5, but I forget the web interface port, I have already tried this https:// localhost:5500/em/ but did'nt work.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the first dbcontrol instance still port 1158 by default? I can't remember how to check that off-hand... apart from stopping and starting it from the command line, which I think displays the URL.

Comment: thanks #Alex my problem is solved by restarting it from cmd line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default port used for `dbcontrol` [is 1158](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbcontrol.htm#ADMIN13416). You may have changed the port though, of course.

The [`emctl` control commands](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbcontrol.htm#ADMIN13419) also display the 'about' URL which includes the port number. For example:

```
$ emctl status dbconsole
Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.3.0
Copyright (c) 1996, 2011 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
https://myhost.mydomain.com:1158/em/console/aboutApplication
...
```